# How to rotate an ViewGroup

Tags: android

I have an FrameLayout and I use WindowManager.addView to show this FrameLayout as a float window. In this FrameLayout there are many subviews such as ImageView and SeekBar. Then I need rotate this FrameLayout through View.setRotate. After this method called, the FrameLayout seems rotated but when I want to interact it by some subviews in it, I found all subviews still in the origin place before it rotated. So how do I rotate an ViewGroup with all its subview?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
int w = mainLayout.getWidth();
int h = mainLayout.getHeight();

mainLayout.setRotation(270.0f);
mainLayout.setTranslationX((w - h) / 2);
mainLayout.setTranslationY((h - w) / 2);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) mainLayout.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = w;
lp.width = h;
mainLayout.requestLayout();
```

This should help.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this is not work for me. My FrameLayout has same width and height so my question is how to rotate subview to correct place. For example, I have an close button in the top right corner of this FrameLayout, when I rotate this FrameLayout 270, this close button should in the top left corner of this FrameLayout. It is show in the top left corner. but when I push the top left corner, there is no act, when I push top right corner, FrameLayout closed.